# Swift-iOS program doesn't run

Tags: ios, swift

I am an android developer and I am learning for Swift now. I am doing the Stanford university CS193P course and trying out some basic calculator program. I followed the instructions but the program doesn't run. It gives me an error.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var display: UIView!




    @IBAction func numberButton(sender:UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle
        print("touched \(digit) digit")
    }




}
```

This is the error

> 2016-07-03 17:30:10.565 Calculator2[2084:121003] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key button.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Please help and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: @MariusConstantinescu i didn't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that you have some issue in your `nib` file. There is an old connection. Try to delete connections properly and if you do not know how to do that, remove your elements from `Storyboard`, add them again and do the connections. This might happen because if you delete IBOutlets in your .`swift` file they do not automatically be removed from `Storyboard`.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's because there's something wrong with one of your `IBOutlet`s. Try deleting and re-doing them. Also, be aware that if you delete an `IBOutlet` in the .swift file, it won't automatically delete it from your .xib or .storyboard, so that's where this problem could come from.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087739/2912892